# Using RegEx with Alteryx to replace string

Tags: regex, alteryx

I have a simple issue: Using Alteryx, I want to take a string, match a certain pattern and return the matched pattern.

This is my current approach:

```
Regex_replace("CP:ConsumerProducts&Retail</td><td><strong><fontcl","[^\<]+","$1")
```

According to various sources and tools like regex101, the first matched sequence should be "CP:ConsumerProducts&Retail". However, Alteryx returns

```
<<<<
```

Alteryx uses the Perl RegEx Syntax (https://help.alteryx.com/2018.2/boost/syntax_perl.html), therefore, it should have no problem with the pattern itself.

I believe I am missing something obvious but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: First, you should match, not replace, second you need the match form start, add '^[^\<]+' in the pattern.

Comment: @PoulBak I have tried your suggestion but with Regex_replace, there is no change in the result, with Regex_match, I get the return 0. Any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 0):

I have received a reply through a different forum. A solution that works for me is to use the following pattern: ([^\<]+).*

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following workflow:

[image]